# PIVOT Operator on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm very new to SQL let alone doing PIVOTS in SSMS. After doing some research, I'm having a hard time doing pivots for two columns.

The data itself when I query it is:

```
SELECT
   INSTRUMENT_ID,
   VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
   ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,
   VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY

FROM
   FACT_TABLE
```

```
INSTRUMENT_ID | VALUE_TYPE_CODE | ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE | VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
ABC           |TOT_AMT          |   3                        |  5.7702
ABC           |AMT_AVAL         |   1                        |  1.9234
ABC           |DRWN_AMT         |   2                        |  3.8468
ABC           |MTD_DRWN         |   2                        |  3.8468
```

Pivoting on **ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
       ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,
       VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
  FROM FACT_TABLE
)
AS Table
PIVOT (MAX (ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ([TOT_AMT], 
                                                                [AMT_AVAL], 
                                                                [DRWN_AMT], 
                                                                [MTD_DRWN])) as piv
```

The outcome is as expected:

```
INSTRUMENT_ID | TOT_AMT | AMT_AVAL | DRWN_AMT | MTD_DRWN
ABC           |3        | 1        | 2        | 2
```

However, I'm trying to produce the following - note the alternating ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE and VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY values per category of VALUE_TYPE_CODE

```
INSTRUMENT_ID |TOT_AMT  |TOT_AMT |AMT_AVAL |AMT_AVAL |DRWN_AMT |DRWN_AMT |MTD_DRWN |MTD_DRWN
ABC           | 3       |5.7702  |  1      |1.9234   |2        |3.8468   |  2      |3.8468
```

So I tried the following that I found from here. It looked simple and I'm still new SQL so it made sense to me. Duplicate the category values or else PIVOT won't work properly.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE+'1' as VALUE_TYPE_CODE1,
       ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,
       VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
  FROM FACT_TABLE
)
AS Table
-- Pivot on ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE
PIVOT (MAX (ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ([TOT_AMT], 
                                                                 [AMT_AVAL], 
                                                                 [DRWN_AMT], 
                                                                 [MTD_DRWN])) as piv
-- Pivot on VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
PIVOT (MAX (VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE1 IN ([TOT_AMT1], 
                                                              [AMT_AVAL1], 
                                                              [DRWN_AMT1], 
                                                              [MTD_DRWN1])) as piv1
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work the way I had hoped for and turned out the following way:

```
INSTRUMENT_ID |TOT_AMT  |TOT_AMT |AMT_AVAL |AMT_AVAL |DRWN_AMT |DRWN_AMT |MTD_DRWN |MTD_DRWN
ABC           | 3       |5.7702  |  NULL   |NULL     |NULL     |NULL     |NULL     |NULL   
ABC           | NULL    |NULL    |  1      | 1.9234  |NULL     |NULL     |NULL     |NULL 
ABC           | NULL    |NULL    |  NULL   |NULL     |2        |3.8468   |NULL     |NULL  
ABC           | NULL    |NULL    |  NULL   |NULL     |NULL     |NULL     |  2      |3.8468
```

I'm wondering if anyone can point out what I did wrong? Is there a slightly easier way? Maybe not an easier way per se, but a solution that is broken down with some explanations.  I've looked some solutions here, and a lot of them just go over my head since I'm still new to this.

I very much appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you provide the pivot statement with more columns than the ones you are pivoting. `piv` does not need `VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY` for its pivot action and `piv1` does not need `ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE`.

There are several solutions for this issue:

1. Add a `group by` and some aggregations to your current solution.
2. Split the pivot actions in two separate actions and join them back on `INSTRUMENT_ID`.
3. Unpivot the original data so that `ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE` and `VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY` are a single column and then pivot into 8 columns in one go. Getting all values in a single column does require a compatible data type for all the values.

**Sample data**

```
create table FACT_TABLE
(
   INSTRUMENT_ID nvarchar(3),
   VALUE_TYPE_CODE nvarchar(10),
   ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE int,
   VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY money,
);

insert into FACT_TABLE (INSTRUMENT_ID, VALUE_TYPE_CODE, ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE, VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY) values
('ABC', 'TOT_AMT' , 3, 5.7702),
('ABC', 'AMT_AVAL', 1, 1.9234),
('ABC', 'DRWN_AMT', 2, 3.8468),
('ABC', 'MTD_DRWN', 2, 3.8468);
```

**Solution 1**

```
SELECT piv1.INSTRUMENT_ID,
       max(piv1.TOT_AMT)   as TOT_AMT,
       max(piv1.TOT_AMT1)  as TOT_AMT1,
       max(piv1.AMT_AVAL)  as AMT_AVAL,
       max(piv1.AMT_AVAL1) as AMT_AVAL1,
       max(piv1.DRWN_AMT)  as DRWN_AMT,
       max(piv1.DRWN_AMT1) as DRWN_AMT1,
       max(piv1.MTD_DRWN)  as MTD_DRWN,
       max(piv1.MTD_DRWN1) as MTD_DRWN1
FROM
(
  SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE+'1' as VALUE_TYPE_CODE1,
       ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,
       VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
  FROM FACT_TABLE
)
AS T
-- Pivot on ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE
PIVOT (MAX (ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ([TOT_AMT], 
                                                                 [AMT_AVAL], 
                                                                 [DRWN_AMT], 
                                                                 [MTD_DRWN])) as piv
-- Pivot on VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
PIVOT (MAX (VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE1 IN ([TOT_AMT1], 
                                                              [AMT_AVAL1], 
                                                              [DRWN_AMT1], 
                                                              [MTD_DRWN1])) as piv1
group by piv1.INSTRUMENT_ID
```

**Solution 2**

```
with cte_piv as
(
  -- Pivot on ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE
  select piv.INSTRUMENT_ID,
         piv.TOT_AMT,
         piv.AMT_AVAL,
         piv.DRWN_AMT,
         piv.MTD_DRWN
  from ( SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID, VALUE_TYPE_CODE, ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE
         FROM FACT_TABLE ) T
  PIVOT (MAX (ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ([TOT_AMT], 
                                                                 [AMT_AVAL], 
                                                                 [DRWN_AMT], 
                                                                 [MTD_DRWN])) as piv
),
cte_piv1 as
(
  -- Pivot on VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
  select piv1.INSTRUMENT_ID,
         piv1.TOT_AMT,
         piv1.AMT_AVAL,
         piv1.DRWN_AMT,
         piv1.MTD_DRWN
  from ( SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID, VALUE_TYPE_CODE, VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
         FROM FACT_TABLE ) T
  PIVOT (MAX (VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ([TOT_AMT], 
                                                              [AMT_AVAL], 
                                                              [DRWN_AMT], 
                                                              [MTD_DRWN])) as piv1
)
select p.INSTRUMENT_ID,
       p.TOT_AMT,
       p1.TOT_AMT,
       p.AMT_AVAL,
       p1.AMT_AVAL,
       p.DRWN_AMT,
       p1.DRWN_AMT,
       p.MTD_DRWN,
       p1.MTD_DRWN
from cte_piv p
join cte_piv1 p1 on p1.INSTRUMENT_ID = p.INSTRUMENT_ID
```

**Solution 3**

```
with cte as
(
  SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID,
         VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
          -- all values require a compatible type for a pivot
         convert(money, ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE) as ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,
         VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
 FROM FACT_TABLE
),
cte2 as
(
  select up.INSTRUMENT_ID,
         up.VALUE_TYPE_CODE + '_' + left(up.ValueType, 4) as NEW_CODE,
         up.Value
  from cte
  unpivot (Value for ValueType in (ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE, VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY)) up
)
select p.INSTRUMENT_ID,
       convert(int, p.TOT_AMT_ORIG)  as TOT_AMT,
       p.TOT_AMT_VALU                as TOT_AMT1,
       convert(int, p.AMT_AVAL_ORIG) as AMT_AVAL,
       p.AMT_AVAL_VALU               as AMT_AVAL1,
       convert(int, p.DRWN_AMT_ORIG) as DRWN_AMT,
       p.DRWN_AMT_ORIG               as DRWN_AMT1,
       convert(int, p.MTD_DRWN_ORIG) as MTD_DRWN,
       p.DRWN_AMT_VALU               as MTD_DRWN1,
       convert(int, p.MTD_DRWN_ORIG) as MTD_DRWN,
       p.MTD_DRWN_VALU               as MTD_DRWN1
from cte2
pivot (max(Value) for NEW_CODE in ([TOT_AMT_ORIG],  [TOT_AMT_VALU],
                                   [AMT_AVAL_ORIG], [AMT_AVAL_VALU],
                                   [DRWN_AMT_ORIG], [DRWN_AMT_VALU],
                                   [MTD_DRWN_ORIG], [MTD_DRWN_VALU])) p
```

[Fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b47be8374c9772344b017bd1437da4b) = solution 1 & 2
[Fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d10083077f860bc9e719ab07e3f5f5d5) = solution 3

Comment: Thank you for this! From the list of solutions you provided, and considering my query overall is large, to me, solution 2 looks generally straight forward to work with, considering my situation. One thing I would like to ask..it appears the WITH + CTE is before the overall query?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for viewers who wants make it dynamic. [Column Value is dynamic]**

For MSSQL SERVER,

```
DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@selectcolumn1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@selectcolumn2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @selectcolumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE) 
            FROM FACT_TABLE f
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 
    SET @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE+'1')
            FROM FACT_TABLE f
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') 

    SET @selectcolumn1 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',MAX(piv1.' + f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE+') as '+ f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE+'_OTV'
        FROM FACT_TABLE f
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') 

    SET @selectcolumn2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',MAX(piv1.' + f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE+'1) as '+ f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE+'_HC'
        FROM FACT_TABLE f
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

  set @selectcolumn=concat(@selectcolumn1,',',@selectcolumn2)

set @query = 'SELECT piv1.INSTRUMENT_ID,
       '+@selectcolumn+'
FROM
(
  SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE+''1'' as VALUE_TYPE_CODE1,
       ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,
       VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
  FROM FACT_TABLE
)
AS T
PIVOT (MAX (ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ('+@cols1+')) as piv
PIVOT (MAX (VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE1 IN ('+@cols2+')) as piv1
                                                              
group by piv1.INSTRUMENT_ID'

execute(@query)
```

FOR MYSQL SERVER

```
SET @col1 = NULL;
SET @col2 = NULL;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(      
 
       'Max(IF(f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE = ''',VALUE_TYPE_CODE,''', ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE, Null)) as ',VALUE_TYPE_CODE,'_OT'
    )
  ) INTO @col1
FROM FACT_TABLE;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(      
 
       'Max(IF(f.VALUE_TYPE_CODE1 = ''',VALUE_TYPE_CODE,'1'', VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY, Null)) as ',VALUE_TYPE_CODE,'_HC'
    )
  ) INTO @col2
FROM FACT_TABLE;



SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
    f.INSTRUMENT_ID,  ', CONCAT(@col1,',',@col2) , 
    ' FROM  (SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID,VALUE_TYPE_CODE,CONCAT(VALUE_TYPE_CODE,''1'') AS VALUE_TYPE_CODE1,ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY FROM FACT_TABLE) f
   Group by f.INSTRUMENT_ID');
  
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember with `PIVOT` is that it transforms the entire result set at that point. All columns not mentioned in the `PIVOT` are effectively used to group the results into rows.

So in your attempt, your first `PIVOT` groups the rows based on `INSTRUMENT_ID` and `VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY`, which is why it produces four rows.

The solution is to pivot the *original* result set twice, excluding unnecessary columns, and then join the results.

So lets break it down using Common Table Expressions:

```
WITH SourceData as (
    SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
       ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE,
       VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
    FROM FACT_TABLE
), OriginalPivotSource as (
    SELECT
       INSTRUMENT_ID,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
       ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE
    FROM SourceData
), OriginalPivot as (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM OriginalPivotSource
    PIVOT (MAX (ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_VALUE) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ([TOT_AMT], 
                                                                 [AMT_AVAL], 
                                                                 [DRWN_AMT], 
                                                                 [MTD_DRWN])) t
), HomePivotSource as (
    SELECT
       INSTRUMENT_ID,
       VALUE_TYPE_CODE,
       VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY
    FROM
        SourceData
), HomePivot as (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM HomePivotSource
    PIVOT (MAX (VALUE_IN_HOME_CURRENCY) FOR  VALUE_TYPE_CODE IN ([TOT_AMT], 
                                                              [AMT_AVAL], 
                                                              [DRWN_AMT], 
                                                              [MTD_DRWN])) t
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OriginalPivot op
        FULL OUTER JOIN
    HomePivot hp
        on
           op.INSTRUMENT_ID = hp.INSTRUMENT_ID
```