# How to use Multiple Aggregates and Pivots to transpose data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

[image: Old Table with Multiple Rows]

I need to transpose the SQL Server table shown here above into the following one:

[image]

[image]

Currently I am just able to do a simple pivot by using

```
Select * 
From 
    (Select SendAgency, Sendinv, AddName, Value 
     From TransAdd) As t
Pivot
    (max(Value) for AddName in (Fee, Commission, Handling, Delivery)) as p;
```

and get this result:

[image]

Please help me in reaching the desired result

Comment: You can combine multiple `pivot` statements. Have a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64132722/pivot-operator-on-two-columns/64133124#64133124)..

Comment: Please supply details of your table schema, sample data as inserts and expected results, all as text and not images.